# .htaccess, .htpasswd across Multiple Joomla instances

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, .htpasswd

I maintain several instances of Joomla on my hosting account mostly 2.5 installations, but some 1.5 installs.

1. Is it possible to use one .htaccess file in the root for all instances. What would i need to modify to make this happen? O
2. I would like to password protect the administrator folders for all of them. Is it possible to do this from the root directory or do i need to have an .htaccess file in each administrator folder? Next question be, how would i code this?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the .htaccess in a dir of your choice and then symlink the file to each root dir of your sites.

```
ln -s /var/www/.htacess /var/www/joomla-site-one/.htacess
```

Then all changes would be mirrored. As long as you dont want extra variations.

Another way would be make a php file and then call it .htacess and tell Apache to run this as php but that has other security issues.